# Properly make Ajax call to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am always getting stuck when creating Ajax calls.  I never know what I am missing.  I think I get everything set up, and then it just doesn't work.  Here is an example:

```
                var urlStr = '@Url.Action("CallPowerShell", "BuildApp", new { param1 = "CSE", param2 = "", param3 = ""})';
                //$.get(url, { param1: "CSE", param2: "", param3: "" }, function (data) {
                //    $("#tAreaID").html(data);
                //    debugger;
                //});
                //debugger;
                alert("work");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlStr,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Hey, Hey, Hey")
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("what is going on here?")
                    }
                });
```

My ajax call, which looks fine to me by simple inspection.
And my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult BuildApp(string param1, string param2, string param3) {
        //ServiceController service = new ServiceController(
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"& 'C:\CI\Scripts\CaptivaBuildScript.ps1' ''";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //return ();
        return Json(output);
    }
```

I am always missing something.  I am not sure what it is this time to be honest?  It looks like I have everything that I need.  However, when I click the link, I never get to the method to debug what is going on in there.  What is everything you need to successfully make an Ajax Get/Post call?

Comment: write your complete click event code

Comment: do you see alert which you are doing alert("work")

Comment: I see that alert().  The url.Action() creates a string.

Comment: see my answer, you will surely will get rid of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake, your are passing wrong, you have misplaced parameters, instead of controller name you placed action and in action place you placed controller which is wrong thats why your ajax call not working:

```
    var urlStr = '@Url.Action("CallPowerShell", "BuildApp",
 new { param1 = "CSE", param2 = "", param3 = ""})';
```

while your action name is BuildApp not your controller name, Url.Action takes first parameter action name and second parameter controller:

```
@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new {object})
```

Do like this:

```
var urlStr = '@Url.Action("BuildApp", "CallPowerShell",
                  new { param1 = "CSE", param2 = "", param3 = ""})';
```

and always use firebug extension to see what is exactly happening with the ajax calls.

Comment: I normally use chromes debug functions which are pretty good as well.  But I still am not calling the .Net get method.

Comment: what is your controller class, you have posted action only

Comment: i have pointed the issue you have, now check whats your controller and action name, check it and see

Comment: CallPowerShellController is the controller name.  I appreciate your analysis but I am still missing something.

Comment: that was your first mistak of mixing action and controller paramter, if after doing that its still not working, then press ctrl + f5 your page and check, may be page is loading from cache

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks and i am glad you got rid of the problem..:)

Answer (score 2):

[**$.ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doesn't have failure function. Use error in place of failure.

```
error:function (){
                    alert("what is going on here?");
                 }
```

And you can always check your browser console for errors, That would help to find whats wrong with your code.

Comment: Did you checked the browser console, for errors. That might help to make it work for you.

Comment: No errors.  I have a warning, which says that some function is depreciated.  No exceptions though.

Comment: If you are able to open the error alert, then there must be some error, check the ajax response in your browser console.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Oh, I needed to have event.PreventDefault().  Silly me :)

Comment: The warning in Ok, but we need the ajax response, when we make an ajax call we can see its response in the browser console, just keep the console open and wait for error alert. Then click on the ajax link in the console. You will seen the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Your url in the ajax call has to be an actual URL string, as in something like http://yourdomain.com. At the client side, Javascript and jQuery have no idea what the server, or server side scripting language is, so you have to pass data that is in an understood protocol, in this case, a URL string.

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://yourdomain.com",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hey, Hey, Hey")
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("what is going on here?")
                }
            });
```

Comment: `@Url.Action` itself generates a fully qualified URL to an action method for the specified action name and route values.